# Windows Store App fails the App Cert Kit test, can't understand why (using WinDbg)

Tags: debugging, winapi, windows-store-apps, windbg, windows-8.1

I've just finished the first version of a Windows 8 Store App. It is relatively simple and all of my "manual" tests are ok (looking for crashes, fatal bugs and so on).
Then I tried to certify it with the Windows App Certification Kit 3.1, but one of its tests fails in the "Crashes & hangs" phase.

Not so much information are given here, only a couple of dump files. I opened them with WinDbg to see what went wrong but it seems very unhelpful here too...

This is the output of the WinDbg's log:

```
Windows 8 Version 9600 MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Built by: 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Dec 11 19:11:48.000 2013 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:03.000
................................................................
.......
Loading unloaded module list
....
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1db0.141c): Unknown exception - code c000027b (first/second chance not available)
eax=0498f4b8 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0498f7e0 edi=0498f4b8
eip=752ea51f esp=0498f79c ebp=0498f83c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal+0x10a:
752ea51f 6a03            push    3

0:006> .ecxr

eax=0498f4b8 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0498f7e0 edi=0498f4b8
eip=752ea51f esp=0498f79c ebp=0498f83c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal+0x10a:
752ea51f 6a03            push    3
```

Where can I read useful information about the failed test?

EDIT: here is the !uniqstack output:

```
0:006> !uniqstack
Processing 16 threads, please wait
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Windows.UI.Xaml.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Spinozapp.ni.exe

.  0  Id: 1db0.578 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef6e000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
003aeac4 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
003aec48 5e2c3af4 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
003aed78 5e2c3a47 twinapi_appcore!WaitCoalesced+0x67
003aeda8 5e2c3d3a twinapi_appcore!Event::WaitWithFreeUnusedLibraries+0x46
003aeee8 5e2c371e twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::RunInternal+0x21a
003aef00 5963ab70 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::Run+0x12
003aef54 704923a0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ApplicationFactory::Start+0xbb
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
003aefbc 72295a26 Windows_UI_Xaml_ni+0x2923a0
003aefd4 743c11d0 Spinozapp_ni!COM+_Entry_Point <PERF> (Spinozapp_ni+0x25a26)
003af028 743ce78c clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
003af0a0 744c42bd clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x152
003af1c4 744c41f9 clr!RunMain+0x1aa
003af438 744c5d62 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
003af474 744c5c23 clr!CorHost2::ExecuteMainInner+0x51
003af888 74a62462 clr!CorHost2::ExecuteMain+0x528
003afafc 74a60678 mscoreei!InvokeAppXMain+0x2bd
003afb38 74adbbcc mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x7e
003afb48 74d3495d mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8c
003afb54 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
003afb98 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
003afba8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  1  Id: 1db0.1edc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef6b000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0201f8b4 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0201fa38 744b8335 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
0201fa9c 744b828b clr!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0x98
0201facc 744b81ba clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xcb
0201fafc 74d3495d clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0xb9
0201fb08 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0201fb4c 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0201fb5c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  2  Id: 1db0.153c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef68000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 2  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
041df8f0 74c41180 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
041df960 743b205a KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
041df990 743b20a1 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x31
041df9e0 743b2007 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a
041dfa18 7451ea01 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152
041dfa5c 74491110 clr!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x61
041dfa9c 745090de clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x6e
041dfaa4 7444500d clr!ComUtil::detail::QIHelper<mpl::type_list<IInitializeSpy,mpl::null_type> >::QI<ComUtil::IUnknownCommon<IInitializeSpy,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type,mpl::null_type> >+0x41
041dfab8 7444507b clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x67
041dfb5c 74445148 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x82
041dfbb8 744ab30a clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x5b
041dfc34 7453fd75 clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0x198
041dfcd4 74d3495d clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x4d
041dfce0 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
041dfd24 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
041dfd34 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  3  Id: 1db0.960 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee3f000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
045bf5fc 7718efc9 ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc
045bf7a0 74d3495d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x259
045bf7ac 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
045bf7f0 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
045bf800 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  5  Id: 1db0.624 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee39000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0484f5d0 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0484f754 751f49bf KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
0484f888 751f4a2d combase!WaitCoalesced+0x73 [d:\blue_gdr\com\published\comutils\coalescedwait.cxx @ 70]
0484f8b0 751f4ae3 combase!CROIDTable::WorkerThreadLoop+0x4b [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\refcache.cxx @ 1480]
0484f9dc 751f4c39 combase!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x21 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 264]
0484f9ec 74d3495d combase!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x16 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 67]
0484f9f8 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0484fa3c 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0484fa4c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Windows.UI.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Windows.UI.ni.dll

.  6  Id: 1db0.141c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee36000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0498f83c 752ea5bd combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal+0x10a [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 971]
0498f850 5e2f5863 combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContext+0x11 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 978]
0498f870 5e2f58b3 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ForwardLocalError+0x77
0498f888 752ea1e4 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::ForwardLocalError+0x30
0498f8d0 752ea6ac combase!CallErrorForwarder+0x9d [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 1104]
0498f8dc 73be2d42 combase!RoReportUnhandledError+0x18 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 1188]
0498f93c 73c7ffc1 mscorlib_ni+0x9b2d42
0498f95c 73c7fd35 mscorlib_ni+0xa4ffc1
0498f98c 6f4ff9df mscorlib_ni+0xa4fd35
0498fa7c 6f4ff965 System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_ni+0x1f9df
0498fae4 73553156 System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_ni+0x1f965
0498faf8 6f4ff934 mscorlib_ni+0x323156
0498fb14 60d6ff16 System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_ni+0x1f934
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0498fb38 743b2a36 Windows_UI_ni+0x9ff16
0498fbb8 72023fb5 clr!COMToCLRDispatchHelper+0x28
0498fc38 720243ba Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessInvokeItem+0x4d0 [d:\wbrtm\windows\advcore\winrt\iwindow\corewindow\dispatcher.cpp @ 794]
(Inline) -------- Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x2e7c [d:\wbrtm\windows\advcore\winrt\iwindow\corewindow\dispatcher.cpp @ 156]
0498fcd4 720216dc Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x2e7 [d:\wbrtm\windows\advcore\winrt\iwindow\corewindow\dispatcher.cpp @ 321]
0498fd34 59639931 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0x60 [d:\wbrtm\windows\advcore\winrt\iwindow\corewindow\dispatcher.cpp @ 390]
0498fd7c 5e2cf45e Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Run+0x5e
0498fd88 5e2cf322 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x27
0498fda8 730c008a twinapi_appcore!Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::HashMap<unsigned int,Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow *,Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::DefaultHash<unsigned int>,Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::DefaultEqualityPredicate<unsigned int>,Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::DefaultLifetimeTraits<unsigned int>,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::Details::SmugglableInterfaceLifetimeTraits,Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::HashMapOptions<unsigned int,Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow *,Windows::Foundation::Collections::Internal::DefaultLifetimeTraits<unsigned int>,0,1,0> >::Remove+0x1c1
0498fe2c 74d3495d SHCore!Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,CScalingInfoBase,ICurrentWindowChangeListener,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>::`vector deleting destructor'+0x11a
0498fe38 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0498fe7c 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0498fe8c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  7  Id: 1db0.1dd8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee33000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 15  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
04cbfa30 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
04cbfbb4 59556702 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
04cbfc20 59556d8b Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowsServices::WaitForObjects+0x58
04cbfd00 59556eeb Windows_UI_Xaml!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadFrame+0x64d
04cbfd10 596f6141 Windows_UI_Xaml!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadMain+0x6e
04cbfd18 74d3495d Windows_UI_Xaml!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadMainStatic+0xd
04cbfd24 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
04cbfd68 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
04cbfd78 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

.  8  Id: 1db0.1d20 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee30000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0560fa78 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0560fbfc 751f5ff9 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
0560fc20 751f5fc9 combase!DefaultWaitForHandles+0x26 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 40]
0560fc40 70197d70 combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x46 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 120]
0560fcc8 74d3495d MrmCoreR!Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::Core::LanguageChangeNotifyThreadProc+0x155
0560fcd4 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0560fd18 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0560fd28 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

. 10  Id: 1db0.764 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee2a000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0588f360 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0588f4e4 7666adca KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
0588f53c 730c2e58 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x159
0588f580 730c2e26 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_WaitForThreadUpdate+0x23
0588f5cc 730c2ea0 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_ThreadProc+0x149
0588f5e0 730c2ef8 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc+0x12
0588f5e8 7718293d SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ThreadPoolCallback+0x16
0588f608 7718f6c0 ntdll!TppSimplepExecuteCallback+0x55
0588f7a0 74d3495d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x487
0588f7ac 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0588f7f0 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0588f800 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

. 11  Id: 1db0.57c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee27000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
05a4f550 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
05a4f6d4 7666adca KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
05a4f72c 730c2e58 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x159
05a4f770 730c2e26 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_WaitForThreadUpdate+0x23
05a4f7bc 730c2ea0 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_ThreadProc+0x149
05a4f7d0 730c2ec9 SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc+0x12
05a4f7d8 74d3495d SHCore!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ThreadProc+0xd
05a4f7e4 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
05a4f828 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
05a4f838 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

. 12  Id: 1db0.187c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee24000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
06ecf718 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
06ecf89c 751f49bf KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
06ecf9d0 75267c91 combase!WaitCoalesced+0x73 [d:\blue_gdr\com\published\comutils\coalescedwait.cxx @ 70]
06ecf9fc 75267d76 combase!CDllHost::MTAWorkerLoop+0x4b [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\objact\dllhost.cxx @ 1016]
06ecfa20 7524111d combase!CDllHost::WorkerThread+0x111 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\objact\dllhost.cxx @ 939]
06ecfa28 751f4ae3 combase!DLLHostThreadEntry+0xd [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\objact\dllhost.cxx @ 846]
06ecfb54 751f4c39 combase!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x21 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 264]
06ecfb64 74d3495d combase!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x16 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 67]
06ecfb70 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
06ecfbb4 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
06ecfbc4 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

. 13  Id: 1db0.1b80 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee21000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0700f9f8 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0700fb7c 751f4be3 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
(Inline) -------- combase!WaitCoalesced+0x5c [d:\blue_gdr\com\published\comutils\coalescedwait.cxx @ 70]
0700fcb8 751f4c39 combase!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x121 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 309]
0700fcc8 74d3495d combase!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x16 [d:\blue_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\threads.cxx @ 67]
0700fcd4 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0700fd18 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0700fd28 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

. 15  Id: 1db0.1df4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee1b000 Unfrozen
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0729f80c 74c6866e ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0729f990 7666adca KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xdc
0729f9e8 754951f4 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x159
0729fa80 75495246 shell32!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_ThreadProc+0x235
0729fa94 75495271 shell32!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc+0x21
0729faa0 74d3495d shell32!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ThreadProc+0xd
0729faac 771b98ee kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0729faf0 771b98c4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x20
0729fb00 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

Total threads: 16
Duplicate callstacks: 3 (windbg thread #s follow):
4, 9, 14
```

Comment: What is you app doing when this happens?  (`!uniqstack` to view unique callstacks)

Comment: The app is opened and closed several times automatically by the Certification Kit, I can't really see a "crash". By the way I've added the !uniqstack output to the question

Comment: Plenty of exact matches when you google "0xc000027b".  Whittle it down from those.